# File group or files group?

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms

If I want to talk about a plural collection (e.g.: set, group,...) I should say group of dogs, set of files,... but is it correct to say **files group, file group, both or neither** in this context (a bunch of files)?

The context is about a lot of files as a collection or another type of group: a set of notebooks (notebooks set? / notebook set?), a pack of hounds (hounds pack? / hound pack?), etc. Perhaps none of these is an alternative correct answer, but I'd like to know if it's possible.

Comment: In this context I'm not talking about file permissions or similar (like file owner, file group,...), I mean lots of files as a collection (group of files) or some other things: a set of notebooks (notebooks set? / notebook set?), a pack of hounds (hounds pack? / hound pack?), etc.

Maybe there is no grammatically correct option to write that, but I'd like to know it

Comment: Erizo, you should modify your question, and include that elaboration. Overly brief questions are prone to misinterpretation, where not everyone initially understands what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, "file group" is ok, as snailboat has written above (and "group of files" too).
When a noun is used to pre-modify another noun, taking on the role of an adjective (example: "chicken soup"), it is called [noun adjunct or attributive noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (Wikipedia).

It seems that in highly specialized texts - technical or legal etc. - attributive nouns may be used in the plural. A [quote](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Holder_Letter_to_Russian_Justice_Minister_About_Snowden) (Wikisource; the article in Wikipedia also treats the issue):

> As you know, Mr. Snowden has been charged with theft of government
>   property (in violation of Title 18, United States Code, Section 641),
>   unauthorized communication of national defense information (in
>   violation of Title 18, United States Code, Section 793(d)), and
>   willful communication of classified **communications** intelligence
>   information to an unauthorized person (in violation of Title 18,
>   United States Code, Section 798(a)(3)). According to news reports and information
>   provided by your government, Mr. Snowden is currently in the transit
>   zone of the Sheremetyevo Airport.

Maybe the quote is off the mark.. as I understand it, here we see several attributive nouns heaped before the head noun.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a noun as attributive, you normally use the singular of that noun. That doesn't imply that, in your case, you are talking about something relative a single file. For example, [user group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Users%27_group) doesn't imply the group is for a single user, or that the group can contain just a single user.
If you want to make more explicit that you are talking of a group of files, you say *group of files*.

Bear in mind that, generally speaking, `a <attributive noun, singular> <noun>` is not always equivalent to `a <noun> of <attributive noun, plural>`. (Compare, for example, "a family business" with "a business of families.")